# React Button to Download file from AWS S3 Bucket using Storage.Get

Tags: html, reactjs, amazon-web-services, download, aws-amplify

I am building a react application and one capability I need is to allow a user to download their own file from S3 storage. I used Amplify to build this application, and so I have been referring to their documentation about storage found [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/download/q/platform/js/#get).

Using their guidance, I created a button to download the file:

```
<Button
     onClick={async () => {
               await Storage.get(this.state.filename, {
                                 level: 'protected',
                                 download: false,
                                 expires: 1000
                     }).then((signedUrl) => console.log("tried fetch", signedUrl));}}
       >
    fetch
</Button>
```

If I open the console, I can see and click the signedUrl from the `console.log()` and it works just fine - I am able to download the document. However, the button itself does not start the download process, and I am not sure why.

Per their documentation, I also tried the following:

```
<a href={this.state.signedURL} target="_blank" rel='noreferrer'>{fileName}</a>
```

I know its not a permissions issue because I can download it by clicking the link in the console.log, but just cannot seem to be able to have the download button initiate it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: Their documentation clearly mentions that you need to set the `download` flag as `true`. This will return the data as a blob and using this result, you can use the method that they mentioned a bit below to add an anchor tag and simulate `click` function to download the file.

Comment: That worked! But I am not exactly sure why that worked whereas their first option did not. Can you explain what's happening here?

Comment: As per their doc, setting `download` to `false` returns a url string and setting it to `true` returns the actual file as blob

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.

**Button:**

`<Button onClick={() => downloadFile()}>Download File</Button>`

**Function:**

```
  const downloadFile = async () => {
    try {
      await Storage.get("fileName", {
        level: "protected",
        download: true,
        cacheControl: "no-cache",
      }).then(resp => {
        window.open(URL.createObjectURL(resp.Body), "_blank");
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("err", err);
    }
  };
```